# Unable to play Agent P card in Phineas and Ferb Uno?

Tags: uno

So we were playing Phineas and Ferb Uno.  I got down to two cards, a green 0 and the "Agent P" wild card.  The card I had to play off of was not green. I laid down the wild card, said "Uno" and declared green.  But immediately I was told I could not play the "Agent P" wild card because the person before me had not played a draw card on me.

Reading from the rules they said:

> Agent P Card - Play Agent P Card whenever someone plays a Draw 2 or Wild Draw 4 on you and that person must draw the designated amount of cards from the discard pile. The Agent P Card is also a wild card where you choose the color that resumes play.

I claimed that because it says it is also a wild card I should be able to play it as a wild card.  They claimed that because that is only as part of the sentence where you resume play after a draw card was played on you, and also because it only mentions playing it when somebody plays a draw 2 or 4 on you, it only counts as a wild card in that case and otherwise it cannot be played.

I claimed this couldn't possibly be right that this disqualified me from playing it as a regular wild card because that would mean I was stuck with this card and wouldn't be able to ever play it - especially when everybody knows I have it, they are never going to play any draw card on me because they know I will just play this card and they will then have to draw the cards instead.

However I was overruled and as a result I couldn't play and had to draw.  Despite having to draw several more cards after a few minutes I actually managed to wind up down to the "Agent P" card as my only card again but didn't get another turn before another player went out - not that it would have mattered since I couldn't have played it anyway.

Is this really the way the game is supposed to be played?  It seems so inherently fair I stopped playing after that hand - I don't really care so much whether I win or lose, but rather I simply get too upset playing in a game that is so inherently unjust that it has a "cursed" card in it that you can't play if someone else finds out you have it, or if you are simply "unlucky" enough that nobody plays a very narrow set of cards right before you.

I looked through the rules myself and the above quote is the only place where it mentions the "Agent P" card.  There are also wild cards which are not "Agent P" cards as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it seems pretty clear that the card can only be played in response to a draw two or wild draw four. It is not the only card you can't play when you want to though in the other case it won't prevent you from playing your last card.

> Agent P Card - Play Agent P Card **whenever someone plays a Draw 2 or Wild Draw 4** on you and that person must draw the designated amount of cards from the discard pile. The Agent P Card is also a wild card where you choose the color that resumes play.

My reading says this card is played in response to but getting an answer from the publisher would help.

Update:

A representative of Mattel Consumer Services replied as follows, confirming this answer as correct:

> Regrettably this card can't be played unless there was a Draw 2 or
>   Wild Draw 4 card played.  I'm sorry this is not the answer you wanted
>   to hear.  You can certainly make a house rule to make any changes to a
>   game, but they must all be agreed upon before play begins.